# How to use cshtml to obtain form values, query the database based on selections, and display the relevant information

Tags: c#, forms, razor, asp.net-webpages

I'm new to C# and am trying to figure out how I get html form values and perform queries based on the selections made.

My database fields are...

BID

TABLE_NUMBER

COMPANY

STATE_CODE

BILL_CODE

RECORD_TYPE

FILLER

BILL_PLAN_DESCRIPTION

For the cshtml, I need to use a dropdown menu that has a list of the states. Based on the selection, upon submitting the form, I need a table to display showing the relevant results for the state selected.

I've tried doing research but couldn't find a simple/understandable solution. Any help is appreciated. It's frustrating because I could do this in 5 seconds with php.

Comment: This is a very broad question.  It might help to break this down into smaller steps.  If you were doing this in PHP, what would be your first step?  Also, the `asp-classic` tag is for ASP pages that predate .Net technology.  Since you are using C#, you probably do not want the `asp-classic` tag.

Comment: Sounds like you are starting at the beginning. There are many tutorials on the asp.net website, start at http://www.asp.net/web-pages.

Comment: this website will not provide u complete code just show us ur effort and then we will help u.....

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple solution to your problem, [Displaying Search Results In A WebGrid](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/180/Displaying-Search-Results-In-A-WebGrid) is probably the best option. In this article Mike Brind explains how to query a database table and how to show the result in a WebGrid.

As suggested by John, you can find several resources on ASP.NET Web Pages at the [Microsoft ASP.NET Site](http://www.asp.net/web-pages) and this is the link to the [ASP.NET Web Pages 2 Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg549171%28v=vs.111%29).